# How to compress an animated GIF?

Tags: animation, resize, gif, compression

I have an animated gif banner 125x125 that needs to be < 10 KB. I started at 60 KB and my best efforts (remove all animation, reduce number of frames) resulted in 28 KB.

Any ideas how to make it < 10 KB? I've tried numerous web tools and apps but nothing seems to help without totally destroying the image quality.

[image]

Comment: Same topic: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5171/10419

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm betting that the photo of the girl is killing your size right now. To test that, remove her frame and replace it with one of the other frames of your animation. I'll bet the size drops quite a bit.

Animated GIFs are best kept small by keeping their color pallets limited, and avoiding continuous tone graphics (photos, gradients, opacity shifts, etc.). Think flat colors - especially at your KB requirement.

Comment: where is the girl :O

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your frame rate to 24 frames per second that will help to decrease file size of .gif 
file.